# Extract channel members from an unknown Telegram public / private channel

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I need a solution, to extract channel members from an unknown Telegram public / private channel. I am not the admin of that channel, But I need those all members list.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st of all, are you in the private group?

Just join the chat first (if not already, done)
You don't need to be an admin to extract user list, you just need to be in that group (if it's a private group)

Getting list of users:

```
async for users in client.iter_participants(chat):
    ...
```

Comment: I tried this solution. It is working fine only in private and public GROUPS, but not in CHANNELS. How can we do this?

Comment: @ShanthiniM you need to be admin in channels to get user list. If you are admin, the above code should work perfectly.